# Roslyn analyser - check for null references for a specific type

Tags: c#, roslyn-code-analysis

I am checking for the possibility to build custom roslyn analyzer for case specifics to our system.

The solution is in .net Framework 4.8. I started with the tutorial [How to write csharp analyzer code fix](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/roslyn-sdk/tutorials/how-to-write-csharp-analyzer-code-fix) and am making my way from there.

The first case I want to check is that when the programmer use the value of a specific service they must not assume that the result is not null.

Take this service definition :

```cs
public interface IConfigurationService
{
   Task<IConfiguration> GetConfiguration(string clientId);
}
```

And a code sample to analyze :

```cs
public async Task DoSomeTask(string clientId)
{
   var configuration = await _configurationService.GetConfiguration(clientId);
   
   // This line should raise a warning because this specific client may not be configurated
   var serviceUri = configuration.ServiceUri;
   DoSomeSubTask(serviceUri);
}
```

So far I got this

```cs
public override void Initialize(AnalysisContext context)
{
   context.ConfigureGeneratedCodeAnalysis(GeneratedCodeAnalysisFlags.None);
   context.EnableConcurrentExecution();

   // The goal is to target the variable declaration (var configuration = ...)
   context.RegisterSyntaxNodeAction(
      AnalyzeDecalaration, 
      SyntaxKind.LocalDeclarationStatement
   );
}

private static void AnalyzeDecalaration(SyntaxNodeAnalysisContext context)
{
   // Check for the type of the variable and exit if it is not 'IConfiguration'
   var symbolInfo = context.SemanticModel.GetSymbolInfo(localDeclaration.Declaration.Type);
   var typeSymbol = symbolInfo.Symbol;
   if (typeSymbol.Name != "IConfiguration") 
   {
      return;
   }

   // Stuck here. I'm pretty sure dataFlowAnalysis is the key, but I can't figure how to use it
   var dataFlowAnalysis = context.SemanticModel.AnalyzeDataFlow(localDeclaration);
   var variable = localDeclaration.Declaration.Variables.Single();
   ISymbol variableSymbol = context.SemanticModel.GetDeclaredSymbol(
      variable, 
      context.CancellationToken
   );
}
```

So that's where I am. I have targeted variable declaration for the target type. Not very much.

Since it is a specific case for a specific type, the analysis does not have to be very fancy. For exemple, I don't need to check for instanaces of `IConfiguration` inside an array, that's not a thing in our code base. Basically juste property access without null check.

Comment: Consider just using nullable reference types and making the result `IConfiguration?` (and yes, you can use NRTs with .NET Framework 4.8, just use a new-style .csproj and bump the language version manually). As NRTs can be opted in and out at the file level if necessary, this can be done without a major impact to the code base of turning NRTs on everywhere isn't desirable (though they're a good idea in general anyway). As a bonus the compiler is much more adept at propagating and eliminating null checks than your custom analyzer could be.

Comment: I'm not sure it will cover my use case, but definitely something I will check

Comment: so essentially you want to force developer to check for null value of configuration . right ?

Comment: Yes, the case of a null configuration is valid and must be handled. But developers usually just assume it is defined.